# Embed libraries into package

Tags: macos, cocoa, opencv

I have a Cocoa application that uses OpenCV, TBB, boost and some other libraries which are installed in my system. How do I create a package that has all this inside so that customer doesn't have to install anything besides just copy/paste my package? 
At the building stage they are referenced via .dylib [image].

Is it possible?

Where I choose in xCode Product\Archive it will only export the app itself.

Comment: More information about. I did replace the .dylib with .a version of libboost and made them to be copied in the [Copy Files] under [Build Phases]. The files indeed to get into the resulting package under Frameworks folder. But the application is still looking for them in /opt/local/lib/libbbost.... Why so? How to tell to check in the Frameworks folder form the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, after a lot of reading I could not find an easy solution. Maybe is there, but I didn't have more time to search for it.

So instead I wrote a small application in C++ that uses `otool` and `install_name_tool` utilities to analyze needed required libraries and copy them into the bundle. Is located here https://github.com/integral-llc/libb . Keep in mind, it was made for personal use, but can be easily changed for anything else.

It worked perfectly for my case. It found all needed dependencies for OpenCV, boost, TBB.

if you have better tools or ideas to improve current one, you are more than welcome to say.